# Output number densities in model atmosphere of the Sun

Tags: python, pandas, homework, jupyter

I have completed my Python project which calculates and outputs the number densities of dozens of different species (over 11 chemical elements total) in a model atmosphere of the Sun. The code reads in a file that contains mass and temperature for a given depth in the Sun.

I would like your thoughts and improvements on my implementation.

Here is the code:

```
# Code which calculates the number densities of all species (HI, HII, H-, e- and the neutral and first ionized component of all the electron donors) given in "The Observation and Analysis of Stellar Photospheres" by David
# F. Gray)

# V2: Tweaked code so now P_e is determined iteratively with Pe-Pg-T relation with Eq. 9.8 of Gray

import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Notation for species:
# H = total number density N for the element
# HI = neutral (makes up part of total number density of element)
# HII (or H+, H_plus) = singly ionized (lose electron) (makes up part of total number density of element)
# H- (or H_minus) = singly ionized (gain electron) (makes up part of total number density of element)

######### INPUTS (CHANGE THESE ASSIGNMENTS ONLY) #########
file_path = "Kurucz.dat" # path to file containing model atmosphere data
log_g = 4.44 
M_div_H = 0
# Teff = 5800 For future use

P_e_num_of_iterations = 300 # Set number of iterations for P_e convergence.
# From trial and error, P_e convergence occurs well before 300 iterations.
######### ######### #########

### Read model atmosphere and prepare data
model_atm = pd.read_table(file_path) # [Mass_Col] = gr/cm^2, [T] = K
mass_col = model_atm['Mass_Col']
T = model_atm['T']

# Constants
k_B = 1.3807e-16 # cm^2 * g * s^-2 * K^-1
g = pow(10, log_g) # cm/s^2

### Standard Solar Abundances from pg. 405 of Gray
Sol_Abundances = {
"A_H": 1.00e0,
"A_He": 8.51e-2,
"A_C": 3.31e-4,
"A_Si": 3.55e-5,
"A_Fe": 2.75e-5,
"A_Mg": 3.80e-5,
"A_Ni": 1.78e-6,
"A_Cr": 4.68e-7,
"A_Ca": 2.29e-6,
"A_Na": 2.14e-6,
"A_K": 1.32e-7
 }
A_List = list(Sol_Abundances.values()) # clone into list just in case

### Ionization Potentials from Appendix D.1 (starts pg. 511) of Gray, units = eV
I_Energies = {
"I_H-": 0.75,
"I_H": 13.598,
"I_He": 24.587,
"I_C": 11.260,
"I_Si": 8.152,
"I_Fe": 7.902,
"I_Mg": 7.646,
"I_Ni": 7.640,
"I_Cr": 6.767,
"I_Ca": 6.113,
"I_Na": 5.139,
"I_K": 4.341
 }


# Partition functions from Appendix D.2 (starts pg. 514) of Gray
# Ordered from theta = 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, ... , 2.0
# Initially, they are represented in log(u(T))
# We will take antilogs (10**log(u(T))) before using them
u_deteminer = [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0]

u_H = [pow(10, x) for x in [0.368, 0.303, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301]]
u_H_minus = [1] * 10
u_HII = [1] * 10

u_He = [pow(10, x) for x in ([0.000] * 10)]
u_HeII = [pow(10, x) for x in ([0.301] * 10)]

u_C = [pow(10, x) for x in [1.163, 1.037, 0.994, 0.975, 0.964, 0.958, 0.954, 0.951, 0.950, 0.948]]
u_CII = [pow(10, x) for x in [0.853, 0.782, 0.775, 0.774, 0.773, 0.772, 0.771, 0.770, 0.769, 0.767]]

u_Si = [pow(10, x) for x in [1.521, 1.111, 1.030, 0.996, 0.976, 0.961, 0.949, 0.940, 0.932, 0.925]]
u_SiII = [pow(10, x) for x in [0.900, 0.778, 0.764, 0.759, 0.755, 0.750, 0.746, 0.741, 0.736, 0.731]] 

u_Fe = [pow(10, x) for x in [3.760, 2.049, 1.664, 1.519, 1.446, 1.402, 1.372, 1.350, 1.332, 1.317]]
u_FeII = [pow(10, x) for x in [2.307, 1.881, 1.749, 1.682, 1.638, 1.604, 1.575, 1.549, 1.525, 1.504]] 

u_Mg = [pow(10, x) for x in [2.839, 0.478, 0.110, 0.027, 0.007, 0.002, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.000]]
u_MgII = [pow(10, x) for x in [0.537, 0.326, 0.304, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301]] 

u_Ni = [pow(10, x) for x in [2.779, 1.753, 1.577, 1.521, 1.490, 1.467, 1.447, 1.428, 1.410, 1.394]]
u_NiII = [pow(10, x) for x in [1.659, 1.386, 1.215, 1.108, 1.037, 0.988, 0.953, 0.927, 0.908, 0.893]] 

u_Cr = [pow(10, x) for x in [4.284, 1.977, 1.380, 1.141, 1.022, 0.956, 0.917, 0.892, 0.875, 0.865]]
u_CrII = [pow(10, x) for x in [1.981, 1.489, 1.125, 0.944, 0.856, 0.813, 0.793, 0.784, 0.781, 0.780]] 

u_Ca = [pow(10, x) for x in [5.238, 1.332, 0.465, 0.181, 0.073, 0.028, 0.010, 0.003, 0.001, 0.000]]
u_CaII = [pow(10, x) for x in [0.825, 0.658, 0.483, 0.391, 0.344, 0.320, 0.309, 0.304, 0.302, 0.301]] 

u_Na = [pow(10, x) for x in [4.316, 1.043, 0.493, 0.357, 0.320, 0.309, 0.307, 0.306, 0.306, 0.306]]
u_NaII = [pow(10, x) for x in ([0.000] * 10)] 

u_K = [pow(10, x) for x in [4.647, 1.329, 0.642, 0.429, 0.351, 0.320, 0.308, 0.303, 0.302, 0.302]]
u_KII = [pow(10, x) for x in ([0.000] * 10)] 

# Make dictionary, keys will become dataframe column names
Gray_D2_dictionary = {'theta':u_deteminer, 'H':u_H, 'He':u_He, 'HeII':u_HeII, 'C':u_C, 'CII':u_CII,
                           'Si':u_Si, 'SiII':u_SiII, 'Fe':u_Fe, 'FeII':u_FeII, 'Mg':u_Mg, 'MgII':u_MgII,
                          'Ni':u_Ni, 'NiII':u_NiII, 'Cr':u_Cr, 'CrII':u_CrII, 'Ca':u_Ca, 'CaII':u_CaII,
                          'Na':u_Na, 'NaII':u_NaII, 'K':u_K, 'KII':u_KII}

# Convert dictionary to Pandas dataframe so we now have a digital version of Gray's Table D.2 (for future use)
Gray_D2_table = pd.DataFrame(Gray_D2_dictionary)
Gray_D2_table.to_csv(r'Gray_Appendix_D2_table.csv', index = False)

# Create function to interpolate u(T) from D.2 table theta column closest to grid point theta
# (grid point temperature)
def Table_D2_u(grid_point_theta, u_species):
    return np.interp(grid_point_theta, u_deteminer, u_species)

# Create phi_j(T) (Saha Eq.) function
def phi_j(u_0, u_1, grid_point_T, grid_point_theta, I):
    result = 0.665*(Table_D2_u(grid_point_theta, u_1)/Table_D2_u(grid_point_theta, u_0))*pow(grid_point_T, 5/2)*pow(10, -grid_point_theta*I)
    return result

# Create function to determine roots from quadratic formula (this will help us when we determine an
# initial electron pressure)
def quadratic(a, b, c):
    # calculate the discriminant
    d = (b**2) - (4*a*c)

    # find two solutions
    sol1 = (-b-np.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
    sol2 = (-b+np.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
    
    return max(sol1, sol2) # return positive root

# Create function to divide each elements of two lists at similar index
def list_divide(test_list1, test_list2):
    res = [i / j for i, j in zip(test_list1, test_list2)]
    return res
      
# Hydrostatic Equilbrium gives total gas pressure
P_g = g*mass_col # Pressure of electrons + Pressure of not electrons

# Ideal Gas Law gives total number density from total gas pressure
N_total = P_g / (k_B*T) # N_H + N_He + N_C + ...

# Use total number density and relative abundances to calculate hydrogen number density, then number densities for
# all other species
N_H = N_total / (1 + sum(Sol_Abundances.values()))
Species_N = {
"N_H_total": N_H,
"N_He_total": Sol_Abundances.get("A_He")*N_H,
"N_C_total": Sol_Abundances.get("A_C")*N_H,
"N_Si_total": Sol_Abundances.get("A_Si")*N_H,
"N_Fe_total": Sol_Abundances.get("A_Fe")*N_H,
"N_Mg_total": Sol_Abundances.get("A_Mg")*N_H,
"N_Ni_total": Sol_Abundances.get("A_Ni")*N_H,
"N_Cr_total": Sol_Abundances.get("A_Cr")*N_H,
"N_Ca_total": Sol_Abundances.get("A_Ca")*N_H,
"N_Na_total": Sol_Abundances.get("A_Na")*N_H,
"N_K_total": Sol_Abundances.get("A_K")*N_H
 }

# Now let us solve for phi_j(T) for every species (for all grid points)
phi_H_minus = []
phi_H = []
phi_He = []
phi_C = []
phi_Si = []
phi_Fe = []
phi_Mg = []
phi_Ni = []
phi_Cr = []
phi_Ca = []
phi_Na = []
phi_K = []

for i in range(len(T)): # iterate by temperature grid points from top to bottom of atmosphere
    theta = 5040/T[i]
    
    phi_H_minus.append(phi_j(u_H_minus, u_H, T[i], theta, I_Energies.get("I_H-")))
    phi_H.append(phi_j(u_H, u_HII, T[i], theta, I_Energies.get("I_H")))
    phi_He.append(phi_j(u_He, u_HeII, T[i], theta, I_Energies.get("I_He")))
    phi_C.append(phi_j(u_C, u_CII, T[i], theta, I_Energies.get("I_C")))
    phi_Si.append(phi_j(u_Si, u_SiII, T[i], theta, I_Energies.get("I_Si")))
    phi_Fe.append(phi_j(u_Fe, u_FeII, T[i], theta, I_Energies.get("I_Fe")))
    phi_Mg.append(phi_j(u_Mg, u_MgII, T[i], theta, I_Energies.get("I_Mg")))
    phi_Ni.append(phi_j(u_Ni, u_NiII, T[i], theta, I_Energies.get("I_Ni")))
    phi_Cr.append(phi_j(u_Cr, u_CrII, T[i], theta, I_Energies.get("I_Cr")))
    phi_Ca.append(phi_j(u_Ca, u_CaII, T[i], theta, I_Energies.get("I_Ca")))
    phi_Na.append(phi_j(u_Na, u_NaII, T[i], theta, I_Energies.get("I_Na")))
    phi_K.append(phi_j(u_K, u_KII, T[i], theta, I_Energies.get("I_K")))

phi_total_data = {'H': phi_H, 'He': phi_He, 'C': phi_C, 'Si': phi_Si, 'Fe': phi_Fe, 'Mg': phi_Mg,
                 'Ni': phi_Ni, 'Cr': phi_Cr, 'Ca': phi_Ca, 'Na': phi_Na, 'K': phi_K,}
phi_table  = pd.DataFrame(data=phi_total_data)


# Determine electron pressure iteratively
P_e = []
for grid_temp in range(len(T)): # iterate by temperature grid points from top to bottom of atmosphere

    # Initial guess for P_e
    # Assumptions: all of gas is element H, no H-
    # N_e^2 / N_HI = phi_H / kT ---> N_e^2 / N_HI = C ---> N_e^2 / (N_H - N_e) = C
    # N_e^2 = C(N_H - N_e) ---> N_e^2 + C*N_e - C*N_H = 0
    N_e = quadratic(1, phi_H[grid_temp]/(k_B*T[grid_temp]),
                    -(phi_H[grid_temp]/(k_B*T[grid_temp]))*Species_N.get("N_H_total")[grid_temp])
    converging_P_e = N_e*k_B*T[grid_temp] # initial guess for P_e

    count = 0
    
    while count <= P_e_num_of_iterations: # loop to converge P_e
        summed_numerator = 0
        summed_denominator = 0

        for j in range(phi_table.shape[1]): # loop to iterate over the elements for summations in Eq. (9.8)
            columnSeriesObj = phi_table.iloc[:, j] # Choose the phi_j column (species) to use
            phi_j_temp = columnSeriesObj.values[grid_temp] # Choose value of phi_j corresponding to grid temperature

            sum_phi_fraction = (phi_j_temp/converging_P_e)/(1 + (phi_j_temp/converging_P_e))

            element_numerator = A_List[j]*sum_phi_fraction
            summed_numerator += element_numerator

            element_denominator = A_List[j]*(1 + sum_phi_fraction)
            summed_denominator += element_denominator

        converging_P_e = P_g[grid_temp]*(summed_numerator/summed_denominator)
        count += 1
    
    P_e.append(converging_P_e) # after number of iterations, we keep the converged P_e

# Ideal Gas Law to determine total free electron number density
N_e = P_e / (k_B*T) 

# Determine number density (ionization) ratios for all species 

N_ratio_H_minus = list_divide(phi_H_minus, P_e) #N_HI/N_H-
N_ratio_H = list_divide(phi_H, P_e) #N_HII/N_HI
N_ratio_He = list_divide(phi_He, P_e) #N_HeII/N_HeI, same convention for other e- donors
N_ratio_C = list_divide(phi_C, P_e)
N_ratio_Si = list_divide(phi_Si, P_e)
N_ratio_Fe = list_divide(phi_Fe, P_e)
N_ratio_Mg = list_divide(phi_Mg, P_e)
N_ratio_Ni = list_divide(phi_Ni, P_e)
N_ratio_Cr = list_divide(phi_Cr, P_e)
N_ratio_Ca = list_divide(phi_Ca, P_e)
N_ratio_Na = list_divide(phi_Na, P_e)
N_ratio_K = list_divide(phi_K, P_e)

# Finally, determine number densities for species requested in HW 3

N_Hminus = []
N_HI = []
N_HII = []
N_HeI = []
N_HeII = []
N_CI = []
N_CII = []
N_SiI = []
N_SiII = []
N_FeI = []
N_FeII = []
N_MgI = []
N_MgII = []
N_NiI = []
N_NiII = []
N_CrI = []
N_CrII = []
N_CaI = []
N_CaII = []
N_NaI = []
N_NaII = []
N_KI = []
N_KII = []

for i in range(len(T)): # iterate by temperature grid points from top to bottom of atmosphere
    
    N_Hminus.append(Species_N.get("N_H_total")[i]/( 1 + (N_ratio_H[i]*N_ratio_H_minus[i]) + N_ratio_H_minus[i] ))
    N_HI.append(N_ratio_H_minus[i]*N_Hminus[i])
    N_HII.append(N_ratio_H[i]*N_HI[i])
    
    temp_N_HeI = Species_N.get("N_He_total")[i]/(1 + N_ratio_He[i])
    N_HeI.append(temp_N_HeI)
    N_HeII.append(Species_N.get("N_He_total")[i] - temp_N_HeI)
    
    temp_N_CI = Species_N.get("N_C_total")[i]/(1 + N_ratio_C[i])
    N_CI.append(temp_N_CI)
    N_CII.append(Species_N.get("N_C_total")[i] - temp_N_CI)
    
    temp_N_SiI = Species_N.get("N_Si_total")[i]/(1 + N_ratio_Si[i])
    N_SiI.append(temp_N_SiI)
    N_SiII.append(Species_N.get("N_Si_total")[i] - temp_N_SiI)
    
    temp_N_FeI = Species_N.get("N_Fe_total")[i]/(1 + N_ratio_Fe[i])
    N_FeI.append(temp_N_FeI)
    N_FeII.append(Species_N.get("N_Fe_total")[i] - temp_N_FeI)
    
    temp_N_MgI = Species_N.get("N_Mg_total")[i]/(1 + N_ratio_Mg[i])
    N_MgI.append(temp_N_MgI)
    N_MgII.append(Species_N.get("N_Mg_total")[i] - temp_N_MgI)
    
    temp_N_NiI = Species_N.get("N_Ni_total")[i]/(1 + N_ratio_Ni[i])
    N_NiI.append(temp_N_NiI)
    N_NiII.append(Species_N.get("N_Ni_total")[i] - temp_N_NiI)

    temp_N_CrI = Species_N.get("N_Cr_total")[i]/(1 + N_ratio_Cr[i])
    N_CrI.append(temp_N_CrI)
    N_CrII.append(Species_N.get("N_Cr_total")[i] - temp_N_CrI)
    
    temp_N_CaI = Species_N.get("N_Ca_total")[i]/(1 + N_ratio_Ca[i])
    N_CaI.append(temp_N_CaI)
    N_CaII.append(Species_N.get("N_Ca_total")[i] - temp_N_CaI)
    
    temp_N_NaI = Species_N.get("N_Na_total")[i]/(1 + N_ratio_Na[i])
    N_NaI.append(temp_N_NaI)
    N_NaII.append(Species_N.get("N_Na_total")[i] - temp_N_NaI)
    
    temp_N_KI = Species_N.get("N_K_total")[i]/(1 + N_ratio_K[i])
    N_KI.append(temp_N_KI)
    N_KII.append(Species_N.get("N_K_total")[i] - temp_N_KI)
    
# Finally, calculate H- number density relative to that of free electrons at each depth
N_Hminus_e_ratio = N_Hminus/N_e

# Collect model atmosphere grid points and number densities of all species into table
N_total_data = {'H-': N_Hminus, 'H-/e-': N_Hminus_e_ratio, 'HI': N_HI, 'HII': N_HII, 'e-': N_e, 'HeI': N_HeI, 'HeII': N_HeII, 'CI': N_CI, 
                'CII': N_CII, 'SiI': N_SiI, 'SiII': N_SiII, 'FeI': N_FeI, 'FeII': N_FeII,
               'MgI': N_MgI, 'MgII': N_MgII, 'NiI': N_NiI, 'NiII': N_NiII, 'CrI': N_CrI, 'CrII': N_CrII,
               'CaI': N_CaI, 'CaII': N_CaII, 'NaI': N_NaI, 'NaII': N_NaII, 'KI': N_KI, 'KII': N_KII}
N_table  = pd.DataFrame(data=N_total_data)

complete_model_atm_table = pd.concat([model_atm, N_table], axis=1)
print(complete_model_atm_table)
complete_model_atm_table.to_csv(r'Model_Atm_Table.csv', index = False)
```

`Kurucz.dat` in its entirety:

```
Mass_Col    T
0.00247550  3854.17
0.00289622  3877.20
0.00371391  3915.87
0.00461186  3947.31
0.00562882  3975.83
0.00679114  4002.68
0.00812965  4028.88
0.00967967  4054.60
0.01147070  4080.70
0.01355500  4106.90
0.01597840  4133.17
0.01879620  4159.76
0.02207450  4186.80
0.02589460  4214.62
0.03034930  4242.54
0.03554540  4271.12
0.04161020  4299.82
0.04868590  4328.47
0.05693600  4357.26
0.06655670  4386.33
0.07778810  4415.62
0.09090170  4445.03
0.10621000  4474.68
0.12408600  4504.64
0.14495800  4534.60
0.16931200  4564.41
0.19773300  4594.56
0.23091900  4624.83
0.26967200  4655.47
0.31491500  4686.52
0.36774100  4718.92
0.42940200  4752.16
0.50133200  4787.18
0.58525500  4824.41
0.68318500  4864.69
0.79739700  4908.81
0.93051100  4958.04
1.08554000  5014.05
1.26597000  5078.42
1.47575000  5153.04
1.71902000  5240.63
1.99961000  5342.94
2.31916000  5463.96
2.67697000  5602.01
3.06065000  5800.44
3.43602000  6041.67
3.78353000  6266.43
4.11264000  6473.71
4.42758000  6699.18
4.72482000  6953.54
4.99668000  7226.88
5.23922000  7508.49
5.44801000  7815.76
5.63283000  8070.74
5.81305000  8273.61
5.99574000  8470.23
6.18778000  8638.82
6.39278000  8815.54
6.61547000  8973.23
6.85950000  9151.00
7.12987000  9320.09
7.43137000  9521.68
7.76945000  9739.64
```

Comment: Can you link some sample data?

Comment: @Reinderien Sure! See the post now for the link.

Answer (score 4):

This is very interesting. I see that it's homework. I can't say whether the output of your code is correct (astrochemistry?), but in terms of Python + Pandas + Numpy development there's some room for improvement.

Overall your code is very flat, has few functions, and operates almost entirely in the global namespace. By analogy, think of a book with no chapter or paragraph separators. This will be difficult to test and modify.

Your nested loops are the reason that the code is slow to execute, particularly your repeated fraction iteration. This needs to be vectorised.

Some assorted specifics:

- You're not using matplotlib, so don't import it
- Constants are OK to live in the global namespace but should be capitalised
- You have a bug where 300 is not actually the number of iterations; it's 301 due to your `<=`
- `u_determiner` should be using `linspace`
- Don't use list comprehensions for your `u_` variables; it's better to externalise this to a CSV (or TSV to match your other data file) and then apply a vectorised power to the whole frame at once
- Don't call `interp` once for every data point; call it with multiple theta points
- Vectorise `quadratic` by putting both solutions in one array and then applying `np.max` over one axis
- `list_divide` shouldn't exist; this is what Numpy vectorised division is for
- Avoid varying your column names with prefixes such as `I_`; it's easier to just have the bare element names. "energy" etc. is implied by the name of the frame.
- Add type hints to your function signatures.
- Start using triple-quoted docstring comments in your functions
- Don't say "create a function to"; that can be omitted
- Don't maintain a `count` variable and don't use `while`; just `for/in` which is more Pythonic
- There's some algebraic simplification needed e.g. in `(phi_j_temp/converging_P_e)/(1 + (phi_j_temp/converging_P_e))`
- Your value for the [Boltzmann constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant) is not as accurate as it could be; it should be 1.380_649e−16. Similarly, the solar surface gravity is not 10^4.44; it's [defined](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/sunfact.html) as 274.0 m/s2 or 27400 cm/s2. This would imply an exponent of 4.43775, but it's better if you skip the log step entirely.

### Suggested

This executes much more quickly, and I didn't want to break anything so it includes a regression test.

```py
"""
Code which calculates the number densities of all species (HI, HII, H-, e- and the neutral and first ionized component of all the electron donors) given in "The Observation and Analysis of Stellar Photospheres" by David
F. Gray)

Notation for species:
H = total number density N for the element
HI = neutral (makes up part of total number density of element)
HII (or H+, H_plus) = singly ionized (lose electron) (makes up part of total number density of element)
H- (or H_minus) = singly ionized (gain electron) (makes up part of total number density of element)
"""

from numbers import Real

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

LOG_G = 4.44
# Teff = 5800 For future use

N_ITERATIONS = 301  # number of iterations for P_e convergence.
# From trial and error, P_e convergence occurs well before 300 iterations.

k_B = 1.3807e-16  # cm^2 * g * s^-2 * K^-1
G = 10 ** LOG_G  # cm/s^2

# Standard Solar Abundances from pg. 405 of Gray
SOL_ABUNDANCES = {
    'H': 1.00e0,
    'He': 8.51e-2,
    'C': 3.31e-4,
    'Si': 3.55e-5,
    'Fe': 2.75e-5,
    'Mg': 3.80e-5,
    'Ni': 1.78e-6,
    'Cr': 4.68e-7,
    'Ca': 2.29e-6,
    'Na': 2.14e-6,
    'K': 1.32e-7,
}
ABUNDANCE_VALUES = np.array(tuple(SOL_ABUNDANCES.values()), ndmin=2).T

# Ionization Potentials from Appendix D.1 (starts pg. 511) of Gray, units = eV
I_ENERGIES = {
    'H_minus': 0.75,
    'H': 13.598,
    'He': 24.587,
    'C': 11.260,
    'Si': 8.152,
    'Fe': 7.902,
    'Mg': 7.646,
    'Ni': 7.640,
    'Cr': 6.767,
    'Ca': 6.113,
    'Na': 5.139,
    'K': 4.341,
}

# Partition functions from Appendix D.2 (starts pg. 514) of Gray
# Ordered from theta = 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, ... , 2.0
# Initially, they are represented in log(u(T))
# We will take antilogs (10**log(u(T))) before using them
U_DETERMINER = np.linspace(0.2, 2.0, 10)

PAIRS = (
    ('H_minus', 'H'),
    *(
        (elm, elm + 'II') for elm in SOL_ABUNDANCES.keys()
    )
)


def table_d2_u(
    grid_point_theta: pd.Series,
    u_species: pd.Series,
) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Interpolate u(T) from D.2 table theta column closest to grid point theta
    (grid point temperature)
    """
    return np.interp(x=grid_point_theta, xp=U_DETERMINER, fp=u_species)


def phi_j(
    u_0: pd.Series,
    u_1: pd.Series,
    grid_point_T: pd.Series,
    grid_point_theta: pd.Series,
    I: Real,
) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    phi_j(T) (Saha Eq.)
    """
    result = (
        0.665
        * table_d2_u(grid_point_theta, u_1)
        / table_d2_u(grid_point_theta, u_0)
        * grid_point_T ** (5 / 2)
        * 10 ** (-grid_point_theta * I)
    )
    return result


def quadratic(a: Real, b: np.ndarray, c: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    determine roots from quadratic formula (this will help us when we determine an
    initial electron pressure)
    """
    # calculate the discriminant
    d = b**2 - 4*a*c
    sqd = np.sqrt(d)

    # find two solutions
    both_sq = np.vstack((sqd, -sqd))
    sols = (both_sq - b) / 2 / a

    return np.max(sols, axis=0)  # return positive root


def calculate_species(N_total: pd.Series) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Use total number density and relative abundances to calculate hydrogen number density, then number densities for
    all other species
    """
    N_H = N_total / (1 + np.sum(ABUNDANCE_VALUES))
    species_N = {
        'H': N_H,
        **{
            elm: abundance * N_H
            for elm, abundance in SOL_ABUNDANCES.items()
            if elm != 'H'
        },
    }
    return pd.DataFrame(species_N)


def calculate_phi(gray_d2: pd.DataFrame, T: pd.Series) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """solve for phi_j(T) for every species (for all grid points)"""
    theta = 5040 / T

    # iterate by temperature grid points from top to bottom of atmosphere
    phi_total_data = {
        elm0: phi_j(
            u_0=gray_d2[elm0],
            u_1=gray_d2[elm1],
            grid_point_T=T,
            grid_point_theta=theta,
            I=I_ENERGIES[elm0],
        )
        for elm0, elm1 in PAIRS
    }

    return pd.DataFrame(phi_total_data)


def calculate_pressure(phi_table: pd.DataFrame, T: pd.Series, species_N: pd.DataFrame, P_g: pd.Series) -> np.ndarray:
    """Determine electron pressure iteratively"""

    # All of these are length-63 vectors
    T = T.to_numpy()
    P_g = P_g.to_numpy()[:, np.newaxis]
    b = phi_table.H.to_numpy() / k_B / T
    N_e = quadratic(
        a=1,
        b=b,
        c=-b * species_N.H.to_numpy(),
    )

    # Initial guess for P_e
    # Assumptions: all of gas is element H, no H-
    # N_e^2 / N_HI = phi_H / kT ---> N_e^2 / N_HI = C ---> N_e^2 / (N_H - N_e) = C
    # N_e^2 = C(N_H - N_e) ---> N_e^2 + C*N_e - C*N_H = 0
    initial_P_e = N_e * k_B * T  # initial guess for P_e

    P_e = initial_P_e[:, np.newaxis]
    phi = phi_table.to_numpy()
    for _ in range(N_ITERATIONS):  # loop 301 times to converge P_e
        sum_phi_fractions = 1 / (1 + P_e/phi)
        summed_numerator = sum_phi_fractions @ ABUNDANCE_VALUES
        summed_denominator = (sum_phi_fractions + 1) @ ABUNDANCE_VALUES
        P_e = P_g * summed_numerator / summed_denominator

    # after number of iterations, we keep the converged P_e
    return P_e


def calculate_ratios(P_e: np.ndarray, phi_with_hminus: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Determine number density (ionization) ratios for all species"""
    return phi_with_hminus / P_e


def calculate_densities(P_e: np.ndarray, T: pd.Series, ratios: pd.DataFrame, species_N: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """determine number densities for species requested in HW 3"""

    # Ideal Gas Law to determine total free electron number density
    N_e = P_e / k_B / T.to_numpy()[:, np.newaxis]

    # vectorise by temperature grid points from top to bottom of atmosphere

    N_Hminus = species_N.H / (1 + (1 + ratios.H)*ratios.H_minus)
    N_HI = ratios.H_minus * N_Hminus

    neutral = species_N / (1 + ratios.drop(columns=['H_minus']))
    ionised = species_N - neutral
    columns = {}
    for col_name in neutral:
        columns[f'{col_name}I'] = neutral[col_name]
        columns[f'{col_name}II'] = ionised[col_name]

    # Collect model atmosphere grid points and number densities of all species into table
    N_total_data = {
        'H-': N_Hminus,
        'H-/e-': N_Hminus / N_e.flatten(),
        'HI': N_HI,
        'HII': ratios.H * N_HI,
        'e-': N_e.flatten(),
        **columns,
    }
    return pd.DataFrame(N_total_data)


def main() -> None:
    # Read model atmosphere and prepare data
    # path to file containing model atmosphere data
    model_atm = pd.read_table('Kurucz.tsv')  # [Mass_Col] = gr/cm^2, [T] = K

    # Hydrostatic Equilibrium gives total gas pressure
    P_g = G * model_atm.Mass_Col  # Pressure of electrons + Pressure of not electrons
    # Ideal Gas Law gives total number density from total gas pressure
    T = model_atm['T']
    N_total = P_g / k_B / T  # N_H + N_He + N_C + ...
    species_N = calculate_species(N_total)

    gray_d2 = 10 ** pd.read_table('u_log.tsv')

    phi = calculate_phi(gray_d2, T)
    P_e = calculate_pressure(phi.drop(columns=['H_minus']), T, species_N, P_g)
    ratios = calculate_ratios(P_e, phi)
    N_table = calculate_densities(P_e, T, ratios, species_N)

    complete_model_atm_table = pd.concat([model_atm, N_table], axis=1)
    ref_table = pd.read_csv('Model_Atm_Table.csv')
    assert np.all(np.isclose(ref_table.to_numpy(), complete_model_atm_table.to_numpy()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`u_log.tsv`:

```
H   HII H_minus He  HeII    C   CII Si  SiII    Fe  FeII    Mg  MgII    Ni  NiII    Cr  CrII    Ca  CaII    Na  NaII    K   KII
0.368   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.301   1.163   0.853   1.521   0.900   3.760   2.307   2.839   0.537   2.779   1.659   4.284   1.981   5.238   0.825   4.316   0.000   4.647   0.000
0.303   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.301   1.037   0.782   1.111   0.778   2.049   1.881   0.478   0.326   1.753   1.386   1.977   1.489   1.332   0.658   1.043   0.000   1.329   0.000
0.301   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.301   0.994   0.775   1.030   0.764   1.664   1.749   0.110   0.304   1.577   1.215   1.380   1.125   0.465   0.483   0.493   0.000   0.642   0.000
0.301   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.301   0.975   0.774   0.996   0.759   1.519   1.682   0.027   0.301   1.521   1.108   1.141   0.944   0.181   0.391   0.357   0.000   0.429   0.000
0.301   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.301   0.964   0.773   0.976   0.755   1.446   1.638   0.007   0.301   1.490   1.037   1.022   0.856   0.073   0.344   0.320   0.000   0.351   0.000
0.301   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.301   0.958   0.772   0.961   0.750   1.402   1.604   0.002   0.301   1.467   0.988   0.956   0.813   0.028   0.320   0.309   0.000   0.320   0.000
0.301   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.301   0.954   0.771   0.949   0.746   1.372   1.575   0.001   0.301   1.447   0.953   0.917   0.793   0.010   0.309   0.307   0.000   0.308   0.000
0.301   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.301   0.951   0.770   0.940   0.741   1.350   1.549   0.001   0.301   1.428   0.927   0.892   0.784   0.003   0.304   0.306   0.000   0.303   0.000
0.301   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.301   0.950   0.769   0.932   0.736   1.332   1.525   0.001   0.301   1.410   0.908   0.875   0.781   0.001   0.302   0.306   0.000   0.302   0.000
0.301   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.301   0.948   0.767   0.925   0.731   1.317   1.504   0.000   0.301   1.394   0.893   0.865   0.780   0.000   0.301   0.306   0.000   0.302   0.000
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I am always learning how to improve. Yes, this is an astrophysics assignment. I am also running this is Pyhton 3.x in Jupyter Notebook, but I got this error running your snippet `/home/Woj/snap/jupyter/common/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py in evaluate(op, a, b, use_numexpr)
    234             # error: "None" not callable
--> 235             return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b)  # type: ignore[misc]
    236     return _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)`

Comment: I don't see the top of the stack trace. Can you indicate which line in the script is failing?

Comment: Being stuck in the global namespace is something you often see with Jupyter notebooks. Often, separation is acquired by using multiple code blocks instead.

Comment: @Mast You're right that it's often, but often does not guarantee good. I would offer that that pattern doesn't teach the right things. Clean code has obvious dependencies, and a global namespace that's as empty as is reasonable for the problem at hand. There are performance implications. Globals won't be garbage-collected, and some numerical code can then suffer from memory pressure.

Comment: @Reinderien It is failing in line 48. `/home/woj/snap/jupyter/common/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/roperator.py in rpow(left, right)
     47 def rpow(left, right):
---> 48     return right ** left
     49 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'int' and 'str'`